# Creating Docker Image using ZIP file

Tags: python, docker, aws-lambda, dockerfile, virtualenv

In AWS lambda function, we upload zip file which contains the program (e.g. python script) and the dependencies. I have that zip file and I want to create its docker image. I don't have the requirements.txt file and I don't want to use that approach. I want my docker image to have all the dependencies required to run the program. I have checked the documentation and couldn't find the solution. Can someone please help me out here?

I tried by creating requirements.txt file by listing all the folders in the zip folder.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to create an AWS Lambda function deployment artifact, you can zip up the files and upload the zip file to S3, or you can do a container based deployment by creating a docker image and uploading that to AWS ECR. The typical way to create a docker image is by defining a [Dockerfile](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/) in your project, and then running `docker build` to create an image from that `Dockerfile`.